# Workflow of a load more button

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I'm building an e-commerce website with React, Node and Mongoose. And I want to first show only 10 products, if there are more products there will be a 'show more' button at the bottom. Once it's clicked I want to show 10 more products ...etc.

I know that I can first fetch all the products and do this at the front end (setting up state and render products base on the state.). But if I have let's say millions of products it would be inefficient I think.

So I wonder what's the right way of doing this? Also, I have few query strings to filter the data like sort by price, ascending order. Can I do this at the back end, for example, adding more conditions like '[10, 19]' to get a certain part of sorted documents and then send to front end? Thank you. :)

Comment: Look into limit and offset: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about mongoose and its possibilities but I assume it's possible for your backend to provide you with a GET/Products with pagination. It means you will have to provide a `pageIndex` (And eventually a `pageSize` to change it easily). This way, you'll get items page per page each time your `more products` button is hit.

So when clicking on the button, you'll GET only 10 items, skipping x item before, x being a math calculation based on the page index you give to the API, something like `pageIndex * pageSize`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to search the keyword "pagination" with Mongoose and have solved my problem. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome, this is the basic behavior we implemented at works for all of our website and it works well and solve a lot of problems that you could meet in front end